# Typescript ReactDOM renders children type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to render multiple children via `ReactDOM.render()`. I get the following type error:

```
Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>[]'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>[]'.
```

```
interface LegacyPageProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const LegacyPage: React.FC<LegacyPageProps> = ({ children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
      const content: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('#react_content');
      if (content) {
        ReactDOM.render(children, content);
      }
  }, [ref, data, children]);

  return ...
}
```

What would be the right type to use for this purpose? The children need to be added to the `#react_content` `id` because the goal of this app is to integrate React in a legacy application. Old and new content is being mixed.

**FIX:** wrap the children in a React.Fragment:
`ReactDOM.render(<>children</>, content);`

Comment: Please provide a sample children example.

Comment: A child could be any React component. In this case, there is no child provided.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Portal, would this fit your needs?

```
const LegacyPage: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, document.querySelector('#react_content'));
}
```

You also don't need to define the children Prop, as it is a type of `React.FC`.